# Popups API - Drupal 6.x-2.0-beta0 - Popup is automatically closing

Tags: blocks

I am trying to add the site contact form in popup using Popups API - Drupal 6.x-2.0-beta0  module. In popups_test.module popups/test page I am able to add the link contact like following

```
function _popups_test_popups() {
  popups_add_popups();
 $output .= '<li>'. l("Contact Us", 'contact',
               array( 'attributes' => array('id' => 'test-popup','class'=>'popups')));
return $output;
}
```

Everything is working fine.

The same thing I am trying to add in a block like following

```
<?php
popups_add_popups();
print l("Contact Us.", 'contact', array('attributes'=>array('class' => 'popups')));
?>
```

Using this the popup is opeing and facing following issue,
1. when I submit the contact form without enter any information the popup is disappearing.  Anyone came across the same issue? Any help will be appreciatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did some analysys and changed the following code its started working

```
$settings['popups']['originalPath'] = $_GET['q'];

//Replaced with following code

$settings['popups']['originalPath'] = 'popups/test';
```

There is a function in popups.js which will check the end point of the form. Not sure exactly the cause of the issue.

```
 return done = (path === Popups.originalSettings.popups.originalPath);
```